# Установить proxy только для одного потока (запроса)

Tags: jsoup, java

Здравствуйте. Есть веб-приложение, которое ищет по разным сайтам разные штуки. Каждый сайт представлен своим классом.  
Появилась необходимость для одного сайта сделать обращение через proxy. 
Делаю так

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "192.168.5.1");  
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "1080");
```

Но в таком случае прокси устанавливается для всех соединений. Если сразу же после установки прокси делать откат к стандартным настройкам, то несколько запросов все равно успевают выполниться с прокси. Как можно установить прокси для отдельного потока (=запроса)?

P.S. Вытягиваю все JSOUP-ом, поэтому использовать класс Proxy не могу.

Comment: > Вытягиваю все JSOUP-ом, поэтому использовать класс Proxy не могу.

Так может все-таки отделить логику создания соединения и получения контента таким образом, чтобы можно было использовать любые классы?

Comment: @a_gura, да, вы правы. Просто с jsoup установить соединение несколько проще.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все-таки не смог сделать установку соединения с сайтом через прокси с помощью jsoup. Пришлось делать так:

```
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", xxxx));
    URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com");
    HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
    uc.setConnectTimeout(20000);
    uc.setRequestMethod("GET");
    uc.setDoInput(true);
    uc.setDoOutput(true);
    uc.setRequestProperty("Referrer", "http://www.exapmle.com");

    String line = null;
    StringBuffer tmp = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        tmp.append(line);
    }

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(String.valueOf(tmp));
```

P.S. Если приложение не многопоточное, то вполне можно обойтись установкой системных параметров прокси.

Answer (score 1):

А почему нельзя задавать url в виде:
http://12.241.123.211:8000/http://www.google.com , например?

Comment: хм.. об этом я не знал. А если передаются параметры post-запроса они не потеряются?

Comment: Если честно, не знаю (самому интересно), попробуйте на практике.

Comment: тот прокси, что я использую, не пропускает так.